# Is this a bug in the text area input that inserts data when custom server-side validation is done?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an MVC view that contains various elements including a checkbox and a text area.

When POST'ing, if the checkbox is selected, the Comment textarea is compulsory.

I created a custom validator that performs this function server-side.

The validator works, and the view returns the validation error correctly when the checkbox is selected and the text area is empty, however when it does return the validation error message, the textarea now has a single comma in it.

I have checked and cannot for the life of me figure out why it is doing it.

As a test I changed the text to a textbox and the problem does not occur.

Is this a bug in the text area input?

For brevity I will endevour to only post the relvant code:

Edit.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ConditionalPass)
        <label class="control-label">Conditional Pass?</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
          <label class="control-label">Conditional Pass Comment</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">            
          @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.ConditionalPassComment, new { @rows = 4, @cols = 6, @class = "form-control" })
          @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ConditionalPassComment)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConditionalPassComment, "A comment is required when conditionally passed", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "font-size:20px;" })
      </div>
</div>
<!-- ./form-group-->
```

ViewModel

```
public class BoardFatViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Conditional Pass")]
    public bool ConditionalPass { get; set; }

    [CommentRequiredIfConditonallyPassed("ConditionalPass", "ConditionalPassComment", ErrorMessage = "An approval comment is required on a conditionally passed FAT.")]
    public string ConditionalPassComment { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Custom Validator

```
public class CommentRequiredIfConditonallyPassed : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly string[] _properties;

    public CommentRequiredIfConditonallyPassed(params string[] properties)
    {
        _properties = properties;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (_properties == null || _properties.Length < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var passStatusPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_properties[0]);
        var passStatusValue = passStatusPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null).ToString();

        if (passStatusValue.ToLower() == "false")
            return null;

        var approvalCommentPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_properties[1]);
        var approvalCommentValue = approvalCommentPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) == null ? "" : approvalCommentPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null).ToString();


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(approvalCommentValue))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }

        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "atleastonerequired"
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters["properties"] = string.Join(",", _properties);

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

Attached is a screen shot of the result.

[image]

The page source for the text area where the , can be seen

```
<div class="col-lg-6">            
    <textarea class="input-validation-error form-control" cols="6" data-val="true" data-val-atleastonerequired="An approval comment is required on a conditionally passed FAT." data-val-atleastonerequired-properties="ConditionalPass,ConditionalPassComment" id="ConditionalPassComment" name="ConditionalPassComment" rows="4">,</textarea>
    <input class="input-validation-error" id="ConditionalPassComment" name="ConditionalPassComment" type="hidden" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-error text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ConditionalPassComment" data-valmsg-replace="false" style="font-size:20px;">A comment is required when conditionally passed</span>
</div>
```

Please let me know if you require any of my other code, but like I said, it I have tested on text area and textbox and it only occurs on the textarea.

Edit 1

As a test, I removed the custom validation code and added a plain old [Required] data annotation and the problem persists, so the problem does not lie with the custom validation.

```
 [Required]
 public string ConditionalPassComment { get; set; }
```

Edit 2.

So it seems to be a problem in the @Html.TextArea and @Html.TextAreaFor helper methods.

If I use the html itself, the problem goes away.

```
  <textarea class="form-control" cols="6" id="ConditionalPassComment" name="ConditionalPassComment" rows="4"></textarea>
  <input id="ConditionalPassComment" name="ConditionalPassComment" type="hidden" value="" />
```

For those who want to perhaps have a look at the source code for the helpers, I am using System.Web.Mvc 5.2.3.0.

Comment: You can try set breakpoint in ModelState and check the value of textarea when post back.

Comment: ModelState.Values[33].Value.AttemptedValue is ",". The question remains why it is there?

Comment: How about inspecting the POST with an http debugger (fiddler or the debug tools in chrome) to see if the comma is included in posted values or it somehow makes it there purely at the server side.